# Does execCommand SaveAs work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, bookmarklet

Why does this not work in ff/chrome?

```
javascript: document.execCommand('SaveAs','true','http://www.google.com');
```

(used as a bookmarklet)

Comment: thanks for the responses. to be more specific, i am trying to force a save-as on a pdf file that i have on the web. 
is there any way i can do this in ff?

Comment: No 30 Minutes later by the same user: [How to force save as dialog box in firefox besides changing headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833068/how-to-force-save-as-dialog-box-in-firefox-besides-changing-headers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

execCommand is not completely standardized across browsers. Indeed, execCommand('SaveAs', ...) only seems to be supported on IE. The recommended way to force a save-as would be to use a content-disposition: attachment header, as described in http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html

Since this is part of the HTTP header, you can use it on any file type. If you're using apache, you can add headers using the .htaccess file, as described [here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html). For example:

```
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
# for older browsers
Header set Content-Type "application/octet-stream"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: i am trying to force a save-as on a pdf file. i don't think I can change the headers

Comment: I think content disposition is part of the HTTP header, not part of the document, so you should be able to use it for pdf files.

Comment: Indeed you can, and here's an example of just that :)

Comment: wow, that's an awesome idea. thanks!
do you know if there is something i could do for forcing save as on pdf files not on my server?

Comment: But more seriously, I don't know. Try opening up another question about that specific topic, maybe someone else will.

Comment: ok, thanks bdonlan. never would've thought of the htaccess file.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to do this in Firefox via [data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs) (see also [Download data url file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file) ) and optionally via the download attribute.

See http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html for an HTML5 shim demo.

[How to force save as dialog box in firefox besides changing headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833068/how-to-force-save-as-dialog-box-in-firefox-besides-changing-headers) also covers this topic.

You can also test it by the following Firefox-tested demo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<script>
var a = document.createElement('a');
//alert(a.download === ''); // If true, this seems to indicate support
a.setAttribute('download', 'testme.png');
a.href = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAwElEQVQ4jWNgGPRgv7Y2z0lj45STpqbHT5iaxhCt8biBgcJJU9PZJ01MPp80MfkPxZOJN8DEpAFJ4/+TJib/T5mY7CdK8wkTkwJ0zVA8naDmk0ZGPjg0/z9hbGyDV/MZY2ORkyYm77FpPmVispwSp6/e7+DAQtj5pqabsdi8myjNUANmY7H99jEjIxWiDDhuauqCxYDD+7W1eYgy4IyxMetJE5PpyH4/ZWqqTZRmGIAm3fsk2YwOjhkZqZCtmVQAAIOlmIi0XoodAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC';
a.innerHTML = 'testing';
a.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
</script>
```

The following also works for URLs as well as JavaScript-initiated loads without the download attribute (though this approach does not allow a file name, it does allow a preview in a new tab):

```
<script>
var myText = 'Hello world!', 
    myHTML = '<b>'+myText+'</b>';

function openFile (textToEncode, contentType, newWindow) {
    // For window.btoa (base64) polyfills, see 
    // https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills
    var encodedText = window.btoa(textToEncode);
    var dataURL = 'data:' + contentType + ';base64,' + encodedText;
    if (newWindow) { // Not useful for application/octet-stream type
        window.open(dataURL); // To open in a new tab/window
    }
    else {
        window.location = dataURL; // To change the current page
    }
}
</script>

<h1>Hello world files:</h1>

<p>Octet stream type to prompts download dialog in Firefox, but with no 
   default file type or path:</p> 

<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ%3D%3D">
    (text example)</a>
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,PGI+SGVsbG8gd29ybGQhPC9iPg==">
    (HTML example)</a>
<button onclick="openFile(myHTML, 'application/octet-stream');">
    (HTML example, from JavaScript)</button>

<p>Quickly viewable (and manually savable) in browser but no dialog presented:</p>
<a href="data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ%3D%3D">(plain text, same window)</a>
<a href="data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ%3D%3D" target="new-tab">
    (plain text--in new tab)</a>
<a href="data:text/html,%3Ch1%3EHello%2C%20World!%3C%2Fh1%3E">(HTML, same window)</a>
<button onclick="openFile(myText, 'text/plain');">
    (text example, from JavaScript)</button>
<button onclick="openFile(myText, 'text/plain', true);">
     (text example, from JavaScript; open in new window)</button>
<button onclick="openFile(myHTML, 'text/html', true);">
   (HTML example, from JavaScript; open in new window)</button>
```

Comment: Loop in mentioning different questions, I came from [How to force save as dialog box in firefox besides changing headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833068/how-to-force-save-as-dialog-box-in-firefox-besides-changing-headers)

Answer (score 3):

As [Microsoft puts it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419.aspx), "There is no public standard that applies to this method."

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't support execCommand. In fact it seems to be IE-only.

Comment: is there a similar firefox function?

Comment: not that I know of, you'll want to use the content-disposition header as bdonlan suggests.

Comment: It (or at least `execCommand`, not `execCommand(saveAs)`) is [documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla) as supported in Mozilla 1.3+