# How to force save as dialog box in firefox besides changing headers?

Tags: javascript, firefox, save

Is there a way to force a save as dialog box for  www.example.com/example.pdf in ff? (i can't change the headers)

Answer (score 4):

If you can output the file to the client in base64, you could use data uris to for the download.

```
location.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + appendPDFContentHere
OR
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,appendPDFContentHere">pdf</a>
```

This will only work in non-IE browsers however but as you requested for firefox, this should work nicely.

EDIT:

Both of the examples below contain the bytes to make a PNG. If you click the first one you can view the image as you normally would in a browser. however, if you click the 2nd link, it will force you to download the image. Save it as a .png and you will see they are the exact same images. The only difference in the two links is the mime type

[view image](http://tinyurl.com/ckcv9b) ([preview shortened url](http://preview.tinyurl.com/ckcv9b)) -- mime type: image/png

[download image](http://tinyurl.com/da2edb) ([preview shortened url](http://preview.tinyurl.com/da2edb)) -- mime type: application/octet-stream

You asked what you put in place of *appendPDFContentHere* and the answer is the base64-encoded bytes that make up the PDF. I used this online [base64 encoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) to encode the image used in the example.

Comment: what should i put in "append PDF content here"?
the entire PDF?

Comment: No, if you just do the URL you can't add the mimetype (application/octet-stream).

Comment: @Tom: The preview links still work and clicking proceed at the bottom works. It just seems that the direct links are broken somehow.

Comment: @fearphage: sorry, it didn't work for me when I tried it a few days ago; I don't know what the problem was, but indeed it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only other way I can think of is modify Firefox settings.  I assume you can't do this.

EDIT:

I cobbled together a client-side solution based on the data URI idea.  It uses a 
modified version of a [base64 encoder](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html) and a technique for 
[binary XMLHTTPrequests](http://web.archive.org/web/20071103070418/mgran.blogspot.com/2006/08/downloading-binary-streams-with.html)  The script downloads the PDF file, then generates and places a data URI link dynamically using the base64 encoder.

It should be useful when you want octet stream encoding but don't have access to the server (as seems to be the case for the OP).

Note, I just posted [an example](http://www.prism.gatech.edu/~mflaschen3/PDFNewWindow/PDFNewWindow.html) using [hunts.pdf](http://www.google.com/ads/hunts.pdf), which the OP was testing with.

```
/**
*
*  Base64 encode / decode
*  http://www.webtoolkit.info/
*
**/

var Base64 = {

    // private property
    _keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

    // public method for encoding
    encode : function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr2raw, chr3, chr3raw, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        //input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

        while (i < input.length) {

            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xFF;
            chr2 = isNaN(chr2raw = input.charCodeAt(i++)) ? NaN : (chr2raw & 0xFF);
            chr3 = isNaN(chr3raw = input.charCodeAt(i++)) ? NaN : (chr3raw & 0xFF);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

        }

        return output;
    }
}



// http://web.archive.org/web/20071103070418/mgran.blogspot.com/2006/08/downloading-binary-streams-with.html
//fetches BINARY FILES synchronously using XMLHttpRequest

load_url = function(url) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET',url,false);
    //XHR binary charset opt by Marcus Granado 2006 [http://mgran.blogspot.com]
    req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    req.send(null);

    if (req.status != 200){
    alert(req.status);
    return '';
    }
    return req.responseText;
}

    function getDataURI(filename)
    {
    var file =  load_url(filename);
    var uueFile = Base64.encode(file);
    var uri = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + encodeURIComponent(uueFile);
    return uri;
    }

 window.addEventListener("load",
                      function()
                      {
                        var link = getDataURI("foo.pdf");
                        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += '<a href="' + link + '"><code>' + link +  '</code></a><br><br>';
                      }
```

Comment: @raj: That's exactly what the headers are for. The response body is the content, the headers are a suggestion what to do with it (e.g. Content-Disposition)

Comment: thanks for the solution. I tried using the code. Here is the bottom of the code I used:


 window.addEventListener("load",
                      function()
                      {
                        var link = getDataURI("http://www.google.com/ads/hunts.pdf");
                        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += '<a href="' + link + '"><code>' + link +  

'</code></a><br><br>';
                      }
</script>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">hello</div>
</body>
</html>

Unfortunately, there was nothing on the html file except the word hello. no pdf. Do I need something else?

Comment: in the link i used "http://www.google.com/ads/hunts.pdf".
I had http in the front of that link, but SO just converts it to a link without the http.

Comment: First of all, you can only do XMLHttpRequest calls on your own server. So copy the PDF to the same server as the HTML page, and try again. If it still doesn't work, enable JavaScript error checking and tell us what errors you get.