# Is there a way to access an Image's bitmap data using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, hash, bitmap, md5

I am looking for a way to create a hash for an image displayed on an XHTML page using Javascript.

Comment: I know that I can use Flash in order to access the BitmapData information. But I'd really like to do it with JavaScript alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get it via XMLHttpRequest.  Note that you would need to play various tricks see http://web.archive.org/web/20071103070418/mgran.blogspot.com/2006/08/downloading-binary-streams-with.html and [How to force save as dialog box in firefox besides changing headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833068/how-to-force-save-as-dialog-box-in-firefox-besides-changing-headers)) to get the file as a binary.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd wish to access an already parsed bitmap data of an image file. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: No.  The actual data should be cached, but you would have to reparse the image in JS.

Comment: You should probably stick with the XMLHttpRequest, it is your most likely solution.

Answer (score 1):

On supported browsers you could use a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas) element to get at image data. Get started with this [Mozilla article on pixel manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas).

Comment: Thanks, but I need to support IE as well. Any ideas?