# Firefox 3.x extensions: dialog "Save As" - choice opener, how open?

Tags: firefox, dialog, save

Is it possible to call Firefox Save As dialog (
chrome://mozapps/content/downloads/unknownContentType.xul ) with
specifying URL?

I found that class for this dialog stored in "nsHelperAppDlg.js" and
called "nsUnknownContentTypeDialog", but i don't understand how to use
it :(

I want to create extension, that show firefox "save as" dialog on
specifying URLl and give a choice which program to save it with.

Help please!

Comment: For the reference, this question in Mozilla newsgroups http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.extensions/browse_frm/thread/c64c4fa7cb2958d4#

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is the [saveURL method](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/content/contentAreaUtils.js#118) in contentAreaUtils.js.  That will give you the exact behavior that Firefox has (since that's what Firefox calls).

Comment: He's actually asking about a different dialog.

Comment: I trying, but this invoke's standard dialog "save as". But i need dialog give a choice which program to save it with.

Comment: Ah, in that case I think you want to use this method:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/uriloader/exthandler/nsIExternalHelperAppService.idl#71

Comment: To sdwilsh - description of that function:
"Binds an external helper application to a stream listener"
Thank you, but it's different function :(

Answer (score 0):

This has helped me in displaying the save-as dialog, or previewing data in-browser

[How to force save as dialog box in firefox besides changing headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833068/how-to-force-save-as-dialog-box-in-firefox-besides-changing-headers)