# HTML: how to create a "save as" button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, save-as

In your browser, when you want to save an HTML page that you are currently viewing, you normally go to the File menu and click Save As.

Can I have a little button at the bottom of an HTML page that does the same thing?  So instead of going to the File menu -> Save As, I want my user to be able to click the button to save the page on to the disk.

There is a solution exists using Javascript as far as I know, but it only works for IE.  See here: [link text](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?s=&threadid=5762)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could have the link run a server side script that loads the HTML file and writes it back to the client with a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=xxx.html` header.

Comment: +1 This will require you to access and change the server's HTTP response header.

Answer (score 3):

The `document.execCommand('SavaAs')` works only in IE but the following link suggests other possibilities you may want to try out.

**[Here is the answer to that :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833015/does-execcommand-saveas-work-in-firefox)**

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [downloadify](http://downloadify.info/downloadify/test.html) jQuery plugin, which using flash to save. Javascript alone is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a button that downloads the HTML file, or the page you're on:

```
<form><input type="button" value="Download Now" onClick="window.location.href='yourpage.html'"></form>
```