# Javascript : File download option from file made of data from browser side

Tags: javascript, web

When i do a JSON call , i get contents of a file.
What i want is that , when pressed a button , this content should be downloadable as a file to the user.

So its like from web UI , browser side ,

my code fires a JSON request and i get some data as reply.
This data should be down-loadable as a file

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [How to create a “save as” button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849500/html-how-to-create-a-save-as-button)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to send the the following http header in the response to tell the browser to download:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.json"
```

Of course when making a JSON call from Javascript to evaluate the response you won't need that header. The easiest way is probably to check for the *X-Requested-With*. If it is set it is probably a request made by JavaScript.