# Write to a text file using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create and edit a text file usinf Javascript.

I have used the following code. But it returns an error.

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

var fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = fso.CreateTextFile("I:\Satheesh\test.txt", True);
s.writeline("HI");
s.close
```

Please note that my Javascript should run only on firefox.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't you think it should be `s.Close();` ??

Comment: You are taking an example in `VBScript` that relies on a proprietary Microsoft API using ActiveX if you used the JScript example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99(v=vs.84).aspx). This will not work.

Comment: @Log1c of course it is s.close

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme the example you provided works only for Internet Explorer

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum see now

Comment: @Tracey that was the whole point. The code you posted comes from an example that only works in IE, and you even took the wrong language version.

Comment: @TheShellfishMeme yes.. That is the reason I am in search of code for Firefox :(

Comment: @Teemu ah.. thats a typo!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284199/in-firefox-write-to-a-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've edited the question.

The original error you were getting:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Is caused by the "set" before the first variable name:

```
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

Which is not valid Javascript. You've (correctly) changed "set" to "var".

```
var fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

So I expect that error message has now gone away - in which case your original question is answered.