# Do I need to handcode forced image downloads with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to make users be able to download high resolution images of my designs when they click the thumbnail. Just left click.

Question: Is this possible using Wordpress a plugin? Or do I need to write [my own version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090272/how-can-i-force-a-image-download) in order to make this happen? Could I just modify a plugin like colorbox?

Comment: why dont you do it as described in the other stack overflow answer?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using the plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-shortcode/

I am here to assist you since I am using the same functionnality in my website (force dowloading of post attachements)

Comment: I like the plugin! How could I use this to download the original png when the user clicks the preview? http://www.freshthreadshop.com/downloads/ is the link, right now its just using Colorbox

Comment: You mean when user clicks on small png?? or when the user clicks on preview itself, already shown?in second case, I think we need to see the code source of content generated by Colorbox and modify it so that it takes into consideration 'force-download.php?file=yourfile.png' onclick on preview. The first case is the normal use of download-shortcode plugin, as described in wordpress.org. Anyways, I promise to download ColorBox and give feedback, it is just i am busy today