# Directly downloading a file in chrome (with extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download, mp3

I am working on a chrome extension that downloads sound files on certain websites with content scripts. When the user clicks the `<a>` tag that points to the .mp3, it opens with chrome's media player. How can I have it automatically download on click, and not open the file?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090272/how-can-i-force-a-image-download

Comment: @netme The JS solution doesn't seem to work in Chrome. For the PHP solution, I'll have to host it separately, because my code is executing in someone else's site. What would I need to do to adapt that code to suit mp3s?