# downloading multiple files from server to client pc using php

Tags: php

I have multiple jpg image files on our server that I am trying to download to my pc.  They are each listed in our database with a path, a title, id, type location found (among other identifiers).  I am trying to download them to directories/sub-directories of location and type for organization purposes.

file_get_contents($path) works, but file_put_contents($destination) puts the images in the server directory the webpage is in, not the local pc path that I pass to it.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong (I'm sure that list is long!).

Here is my code:
// $Image is the array of images with the associated data

```
$TempGet = file_get_contents($absolutepath);  //this seems to work
$TempPut  = "C:\Images\\" . $Image["il_name"] . "\'" . $Image["it_name"];
$TempPut .= "'\'" . $Image["title"] . "-" . $Image["pictureid"] . ".jpg'";
$Result = file_put_contents($TempPut, $TempGet);
```

$absolutepath is "var/www/images/32456.jpg" 
$TempPut ends up as "C:\Images\A\'Red Zone'\'3rd one on left-32456.jpg'

Why is it putting the image on the server and not on my pc?
Thank you.

EDIT: I don't want the pop-up window asking where to save the file; I wanted to be able to download 1000's of images in an organized manner automatically.
Sorry to have left that out.  Thanks

Comment: _I don't want the pop-up window asking where to save the file_ So if this was possible, I could download all existing virus software onto your PC just because you looked at my homepage. That would be fun woudn't it

Comment: Unreal.  I was so focused on getting these 4000 images off the server as fast as possible, I was completely oblivious to how wrong this "path" was.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Also, while searching for examples from the suggestions below, I found this one:  
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754352/download-multiple-files-as-zip-in-php">zip and stream</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `file_put_contents()` will [write data to a file on the server](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

If you want to force the browser to download a file, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090272/how-can-i-force-an-image-download-in-the-browser) or many more.

By the way, you cannot specify the *client* file path as the destination, that's up to the browser. All you can do is tell it to download the image/file.

*EDIT:* as per your edit, you cannot achieve a download from web server to client without the dialog box. This is obviously a security feature implemented into any web browser to prevent websites from filling up your computer with spam, viruses, etc.

It's possible you may be able to achieve it using a Java applet.

The only way you could achieve this with PHP is if your client machine runs a web server too and your server posts a CURL request of some sort to your client's web server.

Comment: And of course the limitation of only being able to download 1 file at once [is trivial to overcome](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php).

Comment: As I said above, I cannot believe how miopically focused I was to not think about these other avenues - like zipping the files.  Duh!  Thank you both for your responses and links (I could not find the answer I was looking for and didn't stop to rethink it).  Thanks again.