# Download in email did not directly download when click on it #html #php

Tags: php, html

I want to create a email body that contains download link, when someone click on the download link, it will be immediately download.

But instead the following code open the image in new tab from the browser. How to solve this problem?

```
$message .= '<a download href="ip-address/img/feature-4.png">Download 
Link</a>';**strong text**
```

p/s:I had tried [force browser to download image files on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click#answer-17527821) ,but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force an Image download in the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090272/how-can-i-force-an-image-download-in-the-browser)

Comment: yep, check this out as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527713/force-browser-to-download-image-files-on-click#answer-17527821

Comment: i had tried the suggested solution, but doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: _"I had tried the suggested solution"_, show us what you tried (add it to your current question) and explain what _"doesn't seems to be working"_ means. Did it still just showed the image in the browser? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: @ Oh, yes, My bar,  I'm gong To remove The comment

Comment: @MagnusEriksson   Oh yes My badante,  I'm gong To remove It.

Answer (score 0):

Add download attribute to link, but this solution works in modern browsers only.

```
<a href="/path/to/image" download="myimage"><img src="/path/to/image" /></a>
```

Comment: IE doesn't support it (which unfortunately is a common browser) and firefox only support it for same origin. Another issue is that the link is in an email. I doubt that email clients (except from web mail clients) support that attribute.

Comment: @Imam I tried your solution, it doesn't seems to be working.