# How to download images without displaying them using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue.js app, I'd like force browser to download image *without displaying it* when a button is clicked.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11090338/517235) answer, I came up with this solution:

```
<span @click="downloadImg(remoteURL)">
        Download Image                  
</span>
```

And the method:

```
downloadImg(url) {
    console.log('downloading', url); 
    document.execCommand('SaveAs',true, url);
    },
```

`remoteURL` is in fact a small function which generates url like this:

```
  remoteURL(link) {        
       return this.BASE_URL+ link  //link is the image's path fetched from database
  },
```

But when I click `Download Image` nothing happens.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311645/download-image-with-javascript/28890083#28890083) is not relevant because I don't want to just `Download image with JavaScript`. What I want is to download image *quietly*, that is without displaying the image.

How can I fix it?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17311705/3634538) might help. It's for jQuery, but the idea is you could use an anchor element as a workaround.

Comment: what about headers sent from server when requesting image - `inline` / `attachment` ?

Comment: @jom I'm not sure how to adopt that jQuery answer to my vue.js scenario.

Comment: @AndrewShmig, not sure how to implement your idea. Please elaborate with code.

Comment: @AndrewShmig That's a good point. @qliq Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#As_a_response_header_for_the_main_body) article about `Content-Disposition`.

Comment: Can you show me  your Vue instance the complete code . I want to know if your getIngUrl it's been generated and how it is relates to the vue instance.

Comment: @Teocci please see my updated question.

Comment: @qliq I'm in the bus now I will reply to you went I get down.

Comment: What is `saveAs` supposed to do? There's no such command in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand). It probably returns false, meaning that command is not supported. It's not clear what you're trying to archive in designMode

Comment: @deathangel908, I don't know. I'm just a noob in JS. I just copied from a relevant answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download image with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311645/download-image-with-javascript)

Comment: @deathangel908,  What works in JS and JQuery, does not necessarily work in vue.js, as I shown here.

Comment: What error did you get? You didn't say anything that you try it in your question,  you didn't post an error either, and I'm 100% sure it works. Saying it woks in js and it doesn't in vue is already silly, because vue runs on js.

Comment: I posted a solution. Please check it out.

Comment: If image is located on a separate domain you may use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49886131/3872976) answer. P.S. update 2 is wrong, it downloads image instead of displaying it if image in same domain. At least the intent of the answer was to download it until chrome deprecated this feature for cross domains.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a solution based on `blob`. First, I created a `blob` using the image `url`.
After the image blob is loaded I called the `saveAs` method extracted from [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to have the blob quietly.

```js
let vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    link: 'https://i.imgur.com/lF1GKDt.jpg',
  },
  created() {
    this.remoteURL();
  },
  methods: {
    downloadImg() {
      let url = this.remoteURL();
      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.blob())
        .then((blob) => {
          saveAs(blob, 'image_name.jpg');
        });
      console.log('downloading', url);
    },
    remoteURL() {
      //return this.BASE_URL + link //link is the image's path fetched from database
      return this.link;
    },
  }
});



var _global = typeof window === 'object' && window.window === window ?
  window : typeof self === 'object' && self.self === self ?
  self : typeof global === 'object' && global.global === global ?
  global :
  this

function bom(blob, opts) {
  if (typeof opts === 'undefined') opts = {
    autoBom: false
  }
  else if (typeof opts !== 'object') {
    console.warn('Deprecated: Expected third argument to be a object')
    opts = {
      autoBom: !opts
    }
  }

  // prepend BOM for UTF-8 XML and text/* types (including HTML)
  // note: your browser will automatically convert UTF-16 U+FEFF to EF BB BF
  if (opts.autoBom && /^\s*(?:text\/\S*|application\/xml|\S*\/\S*\+xml)\s*;.*charset\s*=\s*utf-8/i.test(blob.type)) {
    return new Blob([String.fromCharCode(0xFEFF), blob], {
      type: blob.type
    })
  }
  return blob
}

function download(url, name, opts) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('GET', url)
  xhr.responseType = 'blob'
  xhr.onload = function() {
    saveAs(xhr.response, name, opts)
  }
  xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.error('could not download file')
  }
  xhr.send()
}

function corsEnabled(url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  // use sync to avoid popup blocker
  xhr.open('HEAD', url, false)
  xhr.send()
  return xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299
}

// `a.click()` doesn't work for all browsers (#465)
function click(node) {
  try {
    node.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))
  } catch (e) {
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents')
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 80,
      20, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    node.dispatchEvent(evt)
  }
}

var saveAs = _global.saveAs || (
  // probably in some web worker
  (typeof window !== 'object' || window !== _global) ?
  function saveAs() { /* noop */ }

  // Use download attribute first if possible (#193 Lumia mobile)
  :
  'download' in HTMLAnchorElement.prototype ?
  function saveAs(blob, name, opts) {
    var URL = _global.URL || _global.webkitURL
    var a = document.createElement('a')
    name = name || blob.name || 'download'

    a.download = name
    a.rel = 'noopener' // tabnabbing

    // TODO: detect chrome extensions & packaged apps
    // a.target = '_blank'

    if (typeof blob === 'string') {
      // Support regular links
      a.href = blob
      if (a.origin !== location.origin) {
        corsEnabled(a.href) ?
          download(blob, name, opts) :
          click(a, a.target = '_blank')
      } else {
        click(a)
      }
    } else {
      // Support blobs
      a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      setTimeout(function() {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href)
      }, 4E4) // 40s
      setTimeout(function() {
        click(a)
      }, 0)
    }
  }

  // Use msSaveOrOpenBlob as a second approach
  :
  'msSaveOrOpenBlob' in navigator ?
  function saveAs(blob, name, opts) {
    name = name || blob.name || 'download'

    if (typeof blob === 'string') {
      if (corsEnabled(blob)) {
        download(blob, name, opts)
      } else {
        var a = document.createElement('a')
        a.href = blob
        a.target = '_blank'
        setTimeout(function() {
          click(a)
        })
      }
    } else {
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(bom(blob, opts), name)
    }
  }

  // Fallback to using FileReader and a popup
  :
  function saveAs(blob, name, opts, popup) {
    // Open a popup immediately do go around popup blocker
    // Mostly only available on user interaction and the fileReader is async so...
    popup = popup || open('', '_blank')
    if (popup) {
      popup.document.title =
        popup.document.body.innerText = 'downloading...'
    }

    if (typeof blob === 'string') return download(blob, name, opts)

    var force = blob.type === 'application/octet-stream'
    var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(_global.HTMLElement) || _global.safari
    var isChromeIOS = /CriOS\/[\d]+/.test(navigator.userAgent)

    if ((isChromeIOS || (force && isSafari)) && typeof FileReader === 'object') {
      // Safari doesn't allow downloading of blob URLs
      var reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        var url = reader.result
        url = isChromeIOS ? url : url.replace(/^data:[^;]*;/, 'data:attachment/file;')
        if (popup) popup.location.href = url
        else location = url
        popup = null // reverse-tabnabbing #460
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
    } else {
      var URL = _global.URL || _global.webkitURL
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      if (popup) popup.location = url
      else location.href = url
      popup = null // reverse-tabnabbing #460
      setTimeout(function() {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
      }, 4E4) // 40s
    }
  }
)

_global.saveAs = saveAs.saveAs = saveAs

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = saveAs;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <span @click="downloadImg()">Download Image</span>
</div>
```

### Update:

I removed the jQuery and FileSaver and adapted a vanilla version.

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to do it in vanilla vue.js, without jQuery or external packages.

Comment: @qliq - Unless you want to go the completely vanilla js route (https://gomakethings.com/ajax-and-apis-with-vanilla-javascript/) you must use some kind of library to make http requests to get the image for downloading.  Because vue.js is a library *written in javascript*, most things that work in vanilla javascript (or any other js library) will work in a vue app. All you have to do (most of the time) is wrap them in a vue method and call as desired. If you want to use a library recommended specifically for vue, check out axios: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Answer (score 2):

I used Axios

```
import axios from "axios";
```

---

```
async downloadImage(url) {
  var base64 = await axios
    .get(url, {
      responseType: "arraybuffer"
    })
    .then(response =>
      Buffer.from(response.data, "binary").toString("base64")
    );
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64, " + base64;
  return img;
},
```

---

```
var img = await this.downloadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Test.png");
console.log(img.width);
```

Comment: its only show image width ? how to direct make it download as question ? did you right on answer ? how to understand bro ?

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 2, I recommend using the [eligrey/FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) library.

```bash
npm install file-saver --save
```

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <img v-for="(image, imageIndex) in images"
      :key="imageIndex"
      @click.stop="saveImage(image.url, image.name)
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import fileSaver from 'file-saver'

export default {
  components: {
    fileSaver
  },
  data () {
    return {
      images: [
        {url: 'https://example.com/image1.jpg', name: 'example1.jpg'},
        {url: 'https://example.com/image2.jpg', name: 'example2.jpg'}
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveImage(url, name) {
      fileSaver.saveAs(url, name)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<v-btn @click="downloadImg(responseUrl)">download</v-btn>
```

---

```
methods: {
    downloadImg(responseUrl) {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([responseUrl]));
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", "file.png"); //or any other extension
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    },
},
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: maybe you're right

Comment: image corupt ! It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.